# Changed Partition from NTFS to EXT4 and owner is set to root

Tags: 12.04, games, ext4, steam

I just changed the file-system of one of my partitions to be able to install games from steam on it. It is now ext4 and Owner is set to root, I can not create any folders there or do anything with it. What shall I do?
I'm running ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with windows 7. And that partition is not needed for windows 7.
One more thing I want to ask for, I made a partition for Ubuntu with 20 GB and from windows I see that there are 14 GB free in that partition. Where can I find that in ubuntu?

Comment: `df` will show you partitions and their sizes

Comment: There is a folder in that Partition called : Lost+Found

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/lostfound.html

Answer (score 3):

> I can not create any folders there or do anything with it.

Yes, you can... if you are root that is (since as you claim: root owns it). If you want other users on your system to be able to put files on it: use your admin user to change the owner to your normal user.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER {partitionname}
```

will change the permissions to your current user. $USER might be changed to the actual user name otherwise it will use the one you used to log in. {partitionname} needs to be the directory for that partition.

> Where can I find that in ubuntu?

```
df -H
```

will show a list similar to this:

```
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              300G   100G   200G  33% /
varrun                 2.2G   574k   2.2G   1% /var/run
varlock                2.2G      0   2.2G   0% /var/lock
udev                   2.2G    50k   2.2G   1% /dev
devshm                 2.2G      0   2.2G   0% /dev/shm
```

Comment: I tried partition name : sdc2 it did not work and tried its label it did not work either.
it says : no such file or directory

Comment: do i have to write my user name or just write : USER

Comment: i tried /dev/sdc2
and it did not work

Comment: @user139879 it is $USER and tried the mountpoint (something like  `/media/{diskyouwant}`